# xslt is not transforming generated xml

Tags: sql-server, xml, powershell, xslt

I am completely new to xslt so please bear with me on this question.

I have an XML file I am generating from sqlpackage.exe in a PowerShell script. This is a cut down version of the output (there are a number  nodes but I have only included one here)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeploymentReport xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02">
 <Operations>
  <Operation Name="Drop">
   <Item Value="[dbo].[WORKORDERSchema]" Type="SqlXmlSchemaCollection" />
   <Item Value="[///SourceDB/TargetService]" Type="SqlService" />
   <Item Value="[Foo].[DF_HistoryRawMatchedPPR_ActionDate]" Type="SqlDefaultConstraint" />
   <Item Value="[dbo].[CMLEDGAPPLY_CreateUpdate_CMLEDGAPPLY]" Type="SqlProcedure" />
   <Item Value="[///SourceDB/InitiatorService]" Type="SqlService" />
   <Item Value="[///General/20141027]" Type="SqlContract" />
   <Item Value="[///RequestMessage]" Type="SqlMessageType" />
  </Operation>
 </Operations>
</DeploymentReport>
```

```html
I have created an xslt transform for this to generate the output in a table in html - again cut a down version 

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html"/> 
  
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
    <title>Environment Refresh</title>
   </head>
   <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="DeploymentReport/Operations/Operation[@Name='Drop']">
  <p>
   <table border="1">
    <tr>
     <td  colspan="2">Drop</td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="Item">
     <xsl:sort select="@Type" />
     <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@Type" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@Value" /></td>
     </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </table>
  </p>    
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when I run this I get the following 'empty' html output and I do not know why

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Environment Refresh</title>
  </head>
  <body>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried various options based on my looking around this site but the only way I can get the xslt to work is if I remove xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02" from the DeploymentReport node on line 2 of the xml.

I have tried putting xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02" into the xslt as well and also tried using xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02" format as well but with no luck.

Is anyone able to assist me here please?  As I said I am completely new to this and this is my first attempt at xslt so any help or suggestions are welcome

Comment: Search this site for "XSLT default namespace" and you will find 1000 answers to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace prefix can be declared in the XSLT and in the `select` the prefix can be used for the different nodes as below

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ms="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02"
    version="1.0">
    ....
    <xsl:template match="ms:DeploymentReport/ms:Operations/ms:Operation[@Name='Drop']">
        ....
        <xsl:for-each select="ms:Item">
            ....
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```